# How can set UI for this, where I am using 3 datagrid view in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have been trying to load data in datagrid view but I have to use 3 data grid views and when I am making screen full it appear like this. what changes shall i make to fit it to the screen please help.

[image: full screen issue]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Dock and Anchor properties -- check out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-dock-and-anchor?view=netdesktop-8.0).

You may want a docked grid at the bottom, and another docked grid, one from the top ones. If I understand what you want to achieve correctly, the third grid can just be anchored, without docking.

The linked article explains it thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you so much will try with suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me is to use a `TableLayoutPanel`.

This is your `Form`:

[image: form]

This is your form with a docked `TableLayoutPanel` (I set Form.Padding to 10). Arrange the layout how you want it.

[image: form with TLP]

Add three docked DGV to `TableLayoutPanel`. (I set `RowSpan` of `dataGridViewGreen` to 2).

[image: added DGVs]

This is your form at runtime, after resizing/maximizing.

[image: resized]